# The multi-part identifier "ftr.UserID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run an extract combining threads from multiple forums with the following joins:

- Forum Thread with Forum Name
- Forum Thread Reply with Forum Thread
- User with both

  - Forum Thread and
  - Forum Thread Reply

MY expected output is as follows:

- all Threads
- all Thread replies if they have any

  - expect to have multiple rows for the same thread if they have replies
- I need a user email to appear twice

  - once for the forum thread
  - twice for the forum reply.

When I try to add another "`ON`" for the join, I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>
> The multi-part identifier "ftr.UserID" could not be bound.

If I do not add the extra "`ON`", the second `u.Email` select is simply populating based on the Forum Thread.

Here is my query:

```sql
USE community
-- New Discussions or ideas since 1/1/18 
SELECT 
    f.Name,  
    ft.DateCreated,  
    ft.UserId,  
    u.Email,  
    ft.Subject,  
    ft.Body,  
    ftr.ThreadReplyDate,  
    ftr.UserId,  
    u.Email,  
    ftr.FormattedBody
FROM dbo.te_Forum_Threads ft 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.te_Forum_Forums f
  ON f.ForumID=ft.ForumID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cs_Users u
  ON ft.UserId=u.UserID OR ftr.UserID=u.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.te_Forum_ThreadReplies ftr
  ON ft.ThreadID=ftr.ThreadID 
WHERE ft.DateCreated >= '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY ft.DateCreated DESC
```

Comment: You use `ftr.UserID` field before `dbo.te_Forum_ThreadReplies ftr` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 USE community
-- New Discussions or ideas since 1/1/18 
SELECT f.Name, 
       ft.DateCreated, 
       ft.UserId, 
       u.Email, 
       ft.Subject, 
       ft.Body, 
       ftr.ThreadReplyDate, 
       ftr.UserId, 
       u.Email,   -- ??? twice?
       ftr.FormattedBody
FROM            dbo.te_Forum_Threads ft 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.te_Forum_Forums f          ON f.ForumID=ft.ForumID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.te_Forum_ThreadReplies ftr ON ft.ThreadID=ftr.ThreadID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cs_Users u                 ON ft.UserId=u.UserID 
                                               OR ftr.UserID=u.UserID
WHERE ft.DateCreated >= '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY ft.DateCreated DESC
```

Comment: Yes. I guess I don't know how to select it properly. I want the first u.Email to come from  dbo.te_Forum_Threads. I want the second   u.Email to come from dbo.te_Forum_ThreadReplies

Comment: @BrittneyWilson That's a common problem - one posts not the task but the way which he decided to use for to solve this task whereas this selected way is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I am new to SQL and have trouble finding the right words to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Akina's query, you can implement the second email by joining the Users table again and aliasing as u2, and then alias their email columns accordingly:

```
 USE community
-- New Discussions or ideas since 1/1/18 
SELECT f.Name, 
       ft.DateCreated, 
       ft.UserId, 
       u.Email, 
       ft.Subject, 
       ft.Body, 
       ftr.ThreadReplyDate, 
       ftr.UserId, 
       u.Email as 'Forum Thread Email',
       u2.Email as 'Thread Reply Email',
       ftr.FormattedBody
FROM            dbo.te_Forum_Threads ft 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.te_Forum_Forums f          ON f.ForumID=ft.ForumID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.te_Forum_ThreadReplies ftr ON ft.ThreadID=ftr.ThreadID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cs_Users u                 ON ft.UserId=u.UserID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cs_Users u2                 ON ftr.UserId=u2.UserID
WHERE ft.DateCreated >= '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY ft.DateCreated DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to SQL so I wasn't 100% sure what to call what I was looking to do. Google searches were not helpful because I did not know the terminology. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Sure thing! Food for thought - there are two problematic scenarios which come to mind if you are to apply this to a production db. 1) if you have a large number of users, joining the Users table a second time may be expensive. 2) if you need all emails for each thread in one field (this query gives you the OP, then reply email, then the next row is OP then next reply email, and so on). Those scenarios will need more fine-tuning. Glad to be of help!